# The Coffin-Manson is an extension of the Arrhenius equation

Tags: chemistry

Given the following problem:

Each TV goes through 10,000 on/off cycles in its field life.  The temperature change from these on/off cycles is from 20°C to 60°C.  We can perform thermal cycle testing of the PCB in the TV from 0°C to 100°C without damage to the PCB.  **How many thermal cycles will we need to perform to equal the 10,000 field cycles if m=2.7 for lead-free solder?**

My answer was AF = 11.87; therefore, the number of thermal cycle is 842.48 (10,000/11.87).

However, apparently, the AF = 25; therefore, thermal cycle is 400 (10,000/25).

Not sure how AF = 25 for the above equation. Would appreciate any help to determine why AF = 25 is correct based on the word problem given above. Thank you.

Comment: Why in the world would you think *Mathematics* is the appropriate forum for a question requiring specialized knowledge of physics/chemistry that you couldn't be bothered to provide?